# sql loader truncate always the first column

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I used oracle 10g and I have this file.ctl

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
INFILE '/home/gxs/segmentation/sqlloader/datos.csv'
APPEND INTO TABLE test
(id "s_test.nextval",
name char(10) TERMINATED BY ',' ,
tel char(20) TERMINATED BY ',' ,
apellido char(10) TERMINATED BY ',' )
```

My csv file es

```
name,tel,apellido
daniel,12345,buitrago
cesar,98765,san
alex,4556,ova
```

but when see the table the name haven't the firs caracter:

```
id   name   apellido   tel
1    aniel  buitrago   12345
2    esar   san        98765
3    lex    ova        4556
```

What do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [documentation, you need to use the `EXPRESSION` keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#i1008675) to show that the value is coming purely from the specified expression and is not dependent on anything in the data file:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
INFILE '/home/gxs/segmentation/sqlloader/datos.csv'
APPEND INTO TABLE test
(id EXPRESSION "s_test.nextval",
name char(10) TERMINATED BY ',' ,
tel char(20) TERMINATED BY ',' ,
apellido char(10) TERMINATED BY ',' )
```

... which inserts:

```
        ID NAME       TEL        APELLIDO
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 daniel     12345      buitrago
         2 cesar      98765      san
         3 alex       4556       ova
```

At the moment it's assuming `ID` is a field in your data file, and since you haven't specified a data type it's [defaulting to `char`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#SUTIL1150) with [size `1`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#r3c1-t2), which is consuming the first character of your real first field.